# How to reset printer queue shared by Samba?

Tags: samba, printing, cups

When replacing Ricoh Aficio PLC driver with Ricoh Aficio RPCS driver, Windows clients can niet use the printer anymore because an exception is risen.  The preferences of the printer do not fits the current RPCS driver even if fitted previous PLC driver.

In order to resolve the problem smoothly, i would like to reset all the preference that may be have set to the printer and get the same configuration of a newly created printer (No default config, No driver, No custom preferences).  Creating a new printer do not looks pretty...

How can i reset the configuration of a printer queue which is shared with  Samba 3.6.X?